# Admin form fetch values from dropdown

Tags: adminform, dependency

I have created a custom admin module and in my `Model/Nic.php`, I have created below function

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $nicCollection = Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->getCollection();

    $nicarray = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($nicCollection as $nicList) {
        $nicarray[] = array('-1'=>'Please Select','value'=>$nicList['nic_id'],'label'=>$nicList['nic_name'],'nic_cost'=>$nicList['nic_cost']);
    }

     return $nicarray;
}
```

which gives me below array values when printed **$nicarray**,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Please Select
            [value] => 1
            [label] => America
            [nic_cost] => 3.4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Please Select
            [value] => 2
            [label] => China
            [nic_cost] => 2.3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Please Select
            [value] => 3
            [label] => India
            [nic_cost] => 4.5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [-1] => Please Select
            [value] => 4
            [label] => Japan
            [nic_cost] => 2.5
        )

)
```

Now in my admin form, I am able to fetch values in dropdown format usign **toOptionArray**.

```
$fieldset->addField('nic_id', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('nic')->__('Nic'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'values'    => Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->toOptionArray(),
    'name'      => 'nic_id',
));


$fieldset->addField('nic_cost', 'text', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('coffeecomponents')->__('Nic Cost'),
    'class'     => 'required-entry',
    'required'  => true,
    'name'      => 'nic_cost',
));
```

What I need to do is to fetch the value of **nic_cost** in Nic Cost input field based on what is selected from **dropdown**.

So if admin selects `America` from `dropdown`, then in `Nic Cost` input field the value should be populated with `3.4` (as shown in **array**) and if `China` then value should be `2.3`

How can I change value dynamically when option is changed/selected from dropdown ?

Answer (score 4):

Make your method look like this:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    $nicCollection = Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->getCollection();

    $nicarray = array(
         array(
            'value'=>-1, 
            'label'=>'Please Select'
         )
    );
    foreach ($nicCollection as $nicList){
        $nicarray[] = array(
               'value'=>$nicList['nic_cost'],
               'label'=>$nicList['nic_name']
        );
    }
    return $nicarray;
}
```

Comment: The value has been replaced to `cost`. But I need to save the cost as well as the value i.e. `[value] => 1 and [nic_cost] => 3.4`

Comment: what difference it would make If I change my method to what you have posted ?

Comment: @Mark Your cost will be saved in the db. If you want to save only the id then replace `$nicList['nic_cost']` with `$nicList['nic_id']`.  You cannot save both. but you don't need to. Once you save the id, you will have a reference to your `nic` entity, and you can retrieve the cost from there,

Comment: Okay Marius, lets say I save `nic_id` in my DB, then how can I fetch value for **Nic Cost** i.e. `nic_cost` DB field using onchange event in admin form ?

Comment: @Mark. I wasn't talking about js. I was refering to the frontend...if you needed the value then you could have make an other select to get the cost. If you want to use it in an onchage js event, I think the best approach would be to have a JSON object will all the ids, names and costs, and when changing the select then look in the JSON to see if there is a value for your ID for cost. If so, do with it what you need. SOrry but I have no code for it. The only thing I no is that magento select values support only value and label.

Comment: thanks, but Alas Mage select values support only value and label. I am using jQuery to change values dynamically. Is it good practice instead of using JSON ? Also how can I make default value selected in dropdown from the array which is `China` for the above array ?

Comment: You can make the selected value using `$form->addValues(array('field_name'=>'value'))` after defining your form. Where `field_name` is the name of your field, and value is the id if the `China` entity instance.

Comment: Okay I have used it like this after defining my form `$form->addValues(array('nic_id' => '3'));` and still its not showing me selected option but only the dropdown coming from my Model/Nic.php

Comment: Does `addfield` works for select type ?